# Ограничение роли участника к одной вкладке

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Необходимо сделать ограничение по роли участника(не важно какого, возьмем редактора, например) видимость вкладок админ панели `WordPress`. Сайт использует плагин `WooCommerce` и нужно оставить лишь возможность доступа к вкладке `Товары`(на скрине).

Если у кого-то есть идеи или опыт подобного, прошу дать ссылку на пример или туториал. У самого идей пока никаких.

[image: Скриншот]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не стоит трогать родные роли.

А WC создаёт дополнительную роль "менеджер магазина".
[image: админка менеджера]

Если возможности этой роли не устраивают - сделать копию и изменить с пом плагинов. Напр https://wordpress.org/plugins/user-role-editor/

Answer (score 0):

Используйте плагин [User Role Editor](https://ru.wordpress.org/plugins/user-role-editor/).